# how to generate any graphics to help better visualize the clusters

Tags: r

I have used k-means method to separate some data into two subgroups. What I get is the label (1 or 2) of each sample. Do any of you know how to visualize the clusters? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
> data = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
> k = kmeans(data, centers = 4)
> plot(y ~ x, data=data, col=k$cluster)
```

[image]

Comment: Could I send you my R code in email? Could you be so kind to take a look?